# Ruby BasicObject methods

Tags: ruby, methods, jruby

while going through Ruby, i encountered that BasicObject is the top most superclass of Class. When I tried
 `BasicObject.methods`, i get list of these methods

```
[:method_missing, :singleton_method_added, :singleton_method_undefined, :singleton_method_removed, :new, :become_java!, :allocate, :superclass, :java_class, :class_variables, :<=, :public_instance_methods, :prepend, :class_variable_get, :public_constant, :singleton_class?, :instance_methods, :freeze, :instance_method, :const_defined?, :to_s, :constants, :ancestors, :private_instance_methods, :===, :included_modules, :==, :using, :class_eval, :const_get, :refine, :protected_instance_methods, :public_instance_method, :class_variable_defined?, :inspect, :name, :private_constant, :<, :hash, :>, :>=, :module_exec, :protected_method_defined?, :module_eval, :const_missing, :class_exec, :const_set, :private_method_defined?, :public_class_method, :autoload, :<=>, :include, :public_method_defined?, :autoload?, :class_variable_set, :include?, :remove_class_variable, :deprecate_constant, :private_class_method, :method_defined?, :include_class, :handle_different_imports, :java_kind_of?, :public_send, :frozen?, :protected_methods, :java_implements, :public_method, :java, :singleton_methods, :untaint, :javafx, :enum_for, :private_methods, :method, :instance_variables, :object_id, :extend, :itself, :instance_variable_set, :respond_to?, :java_name, :methods, :to_java, :java_package, :singleton_class, :public_methods, :to_enum, :display, :tainted?, :instance_variable_defined?, :untrusted?, :define_singleton_method, :!~, :nil?, :com, :instance_of?, :java_require, :javax, :java_signature, :tap, :java_annotation, :send, :trust, :instance_variable_get, :is_a?, :eql?, :java_field, :remove_instance_variable, :untrust, :class, :=~, :org, :taint, :kind_of?, :clone, :dup, :!, :equal?, :instance_exec, :__id__, :instance_eval, :__send__, :!=]
```

(I have Jruby present as well so some extra methods)

But when I call `BasicObject.methods(false)` (false parameter for displaying methods of the same class itself), I get

```
=> [:method_missing, :singleton_method_added, :singleton_method_undefined, :singleton_method_removed]
```

I have a query, ideally class.methods with false param should return only its methods and BasicObject.superclass returns nil. Is there any other hierarchy? from where does these methods coming from.

I'm learning Ruby Apologozies if i'm missing something.
Thanks

Comment: I think the methods are JRuby specific, that may add some methods on the class BasicObject. I have that : BasicObject.methods(false)
 => []

Answer (score 1):

You are not asking what instance methods are defined on `BasicObject`, that would be `BasicObject.instance_methods`. You are asking, what methods you can call on `BasicObject`. Well, `BasicObject` is an object just like any other object, so you can call any method on it that is defined in its class (which in this case is `Class`) or in the superclasses of its class (which in this case are `Module`, `Object`, `Kernel`, and `BasicObject`).

Answer (score 0):

Those methods are indeed defined on BasicObject, though they are mostly just empty definitions (`method_missing` actually does some work). Check the [source](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/47a8a24b055cf77f83ee455c95b856abab6cac7a/core/src/main/java/org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java#L1672).

I can't say exactly why, but there could be a hint in the comments:

> Some care has been taken to make the implementation be as monomorphic
>   as possible, so that the Java Hotspot engine can improve performance
>   of it. That is the reason for several patterns that might seem odd in
>   this class.

Those methods are all common hooks that are redefined for metaprogramming purposes. By defining them on BasicObject, it could be that this allows for much faster method resolution by simplifying the inheritance chain.